# extract data from file's name

Tags: oracle, jython, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

My process is supposed to wait for a file with a date which is on file's name like FAP_20150920.txt. Using ODI 12c, how can I extract the name, split it and then fill a column (DATE_MAJ) of my target table with the date.

Thanks in advance

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you want to load the data from the file or you want to extract just the file name?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I would like to load the data from the file and I would like to fill a column which is target table by file's name because the name of the plat file like FAP_20150920.txt.  so I wanna split the file's name and take only 20150920 and put it in my column (DATE_MAJ)

Comment: I wonder why this question has the Jython tag.  What does Jython have to do with Oracle12c?  Are you writing Python (Jython) code to split the filename and add it to the database?

Comment: @DavidCharles who know maybe we can do it by creating a procedure with jython script

Answer (score 0):

Use [OdiFileWait](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/odi/reference/opentools.htm#BEIBGIAI) to detect when file is available. Then you have two options:

- Dirty one: use bash/OS command script to create list of files in a file and load that one first.
- Elegant: use Jython or Groovy to populate ODI variable. Had the code for the it once but unfortunately lost it… :(

Comment: Thanks for your replay... Unfortunately you lost it :'(

Comment: go with dirty one. 99% implementations there would use it anyway. The problem with latter (elegant) is not how to get a list of files in the directory (that's trivial) but passing the Jython/Groovy variable into an ODI Variable

Comment: please tell me how ? I am a new one in ODI